# How to exclude sent and received message log while retriving data from android calllog db

Tags: android

Code for retrieving call logs from database:

```
String[] strFields = { android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, 
android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION };

String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";

Cursor mCallCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, strFields,null, null, strOrder);
```

It is retriving all logs, including recently messaged phone no and time.

But I want to exclude recently messaged items from call log.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: after looking deeper into CallLog columns found **messageid** , which will be null if it is call make sure that this column is avaliable before using it ...                                               ' Cursor mCallCursor = null;
 try{ // Change query check if messageid = ""
mCallCursor=context.getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, strFields, " messageid is null AND " + android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">" + lastcallstamp, null, strOrder);}
catch (final Exception e)
{// messageid column not found }'